# How to disable menu action items after they are selected in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenu, qaction

How can I disable menu action items after they are selected?Ι want the user to be able to select the action only once.

```
Menu=MainMenu->addMenu("menu");
sub1 =Menu->addAction("sub 1");
sub2 =Menu->addAction("sub 2");

connect(sub1, &QAction::triggered, [item, this](){
setBlock1();
});
connect(sub2, &QAction::triggered, [item, this](){
setBlock2();
});
```

Comment: explain yourself better please, do you only want the QActions to be executed at most once?

Comment: Ι want the user to be able to select the action only once.